# How to access an API from the same hostname with Angular 4 frontend and DotNet Core backend?

Tags: c#, angular, api, .net-core

I have an Angular 4 frontend using a .NET Core-backend in the same solution.

As far as I can tell you can't access the window object from Angular the same way, so there's no good way to decode get the current location/environment.

With a .NET Core-backend I also don't have an angular.cli.json file so that I can configure an environments/environment.prod.ts environments/environment.local.ts kind of setup.

What I'm wondering is why I can't access say my backend API without specificing the hostname (which I have trouble accessing) without entering it specifically?

On a localhost it's: http://localhost:port/api// for example but I have to specify http://localhost:port when I want to be able to access it with '/api//' directly.

So when working locally I have one environment and deployed another one. So I can't exactly deploy it with localhost URL.

What is the proper way for Angular's HTTP client to use the same hostname in requests?

I have set up environments like I said, but during release build it does not choose the environment.prod.ts file for example. I guess this has to do with the .NET Core solution rather than Angular.

Any suggestions?

Either by a configuration setup for production/development/local or to get the environmental settings working in a .NET Core solution with Angular 4.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the Startup.cs. AnyWay, if you use Visual Studio 2017 you can use the angular template

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
                {
                    HotModuleReplacement = true
                });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value) && !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("api"))
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/Index.cshtml";
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                    await next();
                }
            });
        }
```

So, a http call can be like

```
this._http.get('/api/controller/action')
```

Comment: What I get is: NodeInvocationException: Uncaught (in promise): Error: URLs requested via Http on the server must be absolute.

Comment: I understood that you want execute and only app with API and angular. So you must say to the app, when you want to serve a api, and when a index.html. If are two different app, in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2017/04/25/custom-environ-asp-net-core/ explain using custom Enviroment